Why did FIDE increase ratings of players under 2000 by quite a bit in March?
In March 2024, FIDE increased the rating of players by 10*(2000 - rating)/4, and my own rating shot up by about 300 points! I have a few questions:
1 - Why did FIDE increase the rating?
2 - Why did FIDE increase the rated player limit to 1400?
3 - Did FIDE introduce an update to the FIDE rating regulations handbook?
An answer to any of these three questions will be much appreciated!

The official reasons have been listed so here's the unofficial one: FIDE grabs money from every master title so it's in their best interest to inflate ratings.

Ha! Nice one David!


Lack of tournaments during COVID19 led to a lot of players being underrated. After COVID19 they started playing and caused some rating deflation, due to (by rating) stronger players underperforming against them (due to them being underrated). This even worsened decade-long rating deflation. So FIDE decided to raise the lower ratings and thus lessen rating deflation at higher ratings. Jeff Sonas, who proposed rating change with this proposal, explains that change is needed due to decade-long deflation, made worse by COVID19.

It didn't only raise rating limit to 1400 - it compressed rating range 1000-2000 to 1400-2000, thus making player ratings closer together, thus addressing problems Sonas pointed out (ratings being further away than results suggest).

They updated regulations in january, see announcement.


